# Convert project to DX - community page

Tags: salesforcedx, convert

So I followed the instruction to converting an existing project to DX.

- Created a unmanaged package.
- Retrieved and converted the zip file.

All good so far.

When I pushed my code to a scratch org, I don't see my community page I had created.  Going under "All Communities", I have nothing listed.

I looked everywhere in the package manager for community pages so that I can add it to my unmanaged package, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

How to I get my community page I created from my current non DX project into my scratch org as part of the converted to DX project?

Comment: lightning communties? if so - is your sites xml file configured? what about siteDotComSites folder? pages ? you will need to provide more details as to how your SFDX setup is configured

Comment: I tried another venue and now I'm getting errors, which looks like i need to fix those errors before I can convert to DX.

Comment: I used my local git repo of the project to retrieve the package.xml file.  force:mdapi:retrieve  -k pathToPackage.xml -r ./tem -u myscratch1